# jQuery replace href and change url in every <a>

Tags: jquery, url, replace, href

I'm new to jQuery and I'm trying to replace numerous link by another one, but I can't seem to find why it doesn't, could you help me please.

Code:

First attempt:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    $("a").each(function() { 

        newUrl += $(this).href+ textOfNew + " ";

        this.href = this.href.replace((this.href), newUrl);

    });

});
```

Second attempt:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    $("a").each(function() { 
        $("$(this).href").val(function(i, val) {
            var newUrl = "test" ;

            return = $(this).href.replace($(this).href, newUrl);
        }); 
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
   $("a").each(function() { 

          var newUrl =  $(this).attr('href')+ textOfNew + " ";

              $(this).attr('href',newUrl);

    });
```

Comment: You don't need `each()`, just pass an anonymous function to the `attr()` method. As [@adeneo shows](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15452088/82548).

Answer (score 2):

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $("a").attr('href', function(i, href) {
        return href + '/test';
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/VqUuw/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("a").each(function() { 

    newUrl += $(this).attr("href") + textOfNew + " ";

    $(this).attr("href", newUrl);

});
```